# How to know and raise exact exception in Django views

Tags: python, django, exception, error-handling

There are many at times we write code inside try: and except: block in Django. But my confusion is what to write inside exception: block or how to know what is the exact error and raise it.

For ex: In this particular case I am invoking an utility function from my views.py, and I have written like this.

```
try:
    res = process_my_data(request, name, email)
except:
    import sys
    print sys.exc_value
```

Inside the process_my_data() definition I am doing some kind of DB operations. If it fails, and comes to except block what should I write here. I am not sure what to write that is why written `print sys.exc_value`

Comment: Why the hell this question is down voted, pls add your comment mate.

Comment: you'd benefit from reading [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: Shouldn't your utility function throw the exception if one of it's methods fails, instead of your view code?

Comment: Right Brandon, I can use the try: except: block inside utility function, but I am unaware which exception should I throw or raise.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest question you have to ask yourself is "why am I writing this as a try except in the first place?" Do you know that what is inside the try is capable of throwing an exception? If the answer to that is yes, then surely you know what type of exception to catch. In this instance it seems like it depends on what backend DB library you are using. Look up the documentation for the one you're using. From there it's really up to you what you want to do within the except - how do you want your program to behave if an exception is thrown? At the absolute minimum I would catch a general exception and print the output to the console with something like this:

```
except Exception, e:        
        message = str(e)
        print (message)
```